# How to use StringFromFile function within a JSR223 Sampler?

Tags: jmeter, datasource, jsr223

I can't find any good docs/examples on how to use the StringFromFile function to get multiple records from a source data file from within a JSR223 Sampler. Could somebody please help me?

My code which doesn't work:

```
String filename = "filename.csv";

String record = StringFromFile(filename,"id");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using it directly in the scripts, as per [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) documentation:

> When using this feature, ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables directly in script code as caching would only cache first replacement. Instead use script parameters.

So the solution would be using [File.readLines()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#readLines()) function which reads the file into a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of strings

[image]

More information: [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter/)

Comment: The above is really slow.. any way to better design the above?